# Tkinter scrollbar is not scrolling

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

As part of a tkinter app I'm building using Python 3.8, I need a particular tab in a Notebook to be scrollable. The notebook needs to remain at a fixed size, but the problem is that there will be cases in which the contents of the tab will exceed the size of the notebook.

The scrollbar appears as it should, but scrolling appears to have no effect on the contents of the tab. It looks like it thinks it's scrolling something but I do not know what. Here's an isolated example of a tab with a scrollbar which has no effect:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tabs = ttk.Notebook(root, width=200, height=650)

tab_options = tk.Frame(tabs)
tabs.add(tab_options, text="Options")


main_frame = tk.Frame(tab_options)
main_frame.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame)
canvas.pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=1)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y",expand=1)

lf_options = tk.Frame(canvas)
lf_options.pack()

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,200,1000))

for i in range(50):
    ttk.Label(lf_options, text=str(i)).pack()

tabs.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I imagine it's something to do with how I'm hooking up the frames to the canvas but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I've seen suggestions about setting scrollregion to

```
canvas.bbox("all")
```

but I don't understand how to associate that with the maximum height that can be displayed, i.e. the height of the notebook itself. Using that as the scrollregion also just makes the scrollbar unscrollable.

I know there are many similar questions on here, but I have not found any of those examples to work in this case.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A Canvas does not scroll *child widgets* (like your `lf_options` currently is), it scrolls *drawing objects* which are added via the various `.create_XXXX()` methods.  Use `.create_window()` to make your Frame visible rather than `.pack()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I removed `lf_options.pack()` and replaced it with `canvas.create_window((0,0), window=lf_options, anchor="nw")`. There is now no visible scrollbar, and for some reason the Labels stop being created after reaching 13... Any idea what is going on there?

Answer (score 1):

It seems more logical to use a `tk.Listbox` for this purpose, see below for example an edited version of your code. Here the scrollbar works just as expected!

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tabs = ttk.Notebook(root, width=200, height=650)

tab_options = tk.Frame(tabs)
tabs.add(tab_options, text="Options")

listbox = tk.Listbox(tab_options)
for i in range(50):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, f"Number {i}")
listbox.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(tab_options, orient="vertical", command=listbox.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=1)

listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

tabs.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are missing Label widget.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, I should have been clearer. You're right that a listbox would do it in the example I posted, but the frame I'm trying to scroll in my build contains other widgets, and their contents depend on selections made elsewhere in the app.